# Can't restore value, why?

Tags: java, android

this is my application (basic) to set values of a `TextView` via a dialog's `EditText`.

I want to set the `TextView` at 0 at the very first time of the launch of the app, and then I want to save the state of the value so that when you open it back, the same value is there.

I'll leave you my pieces of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int currentMoney;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    SharedPreferences mDefaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int current = savedInstanceState.getInt("current");
    if (mDefaultPreferences.getBoolean("first_launch", true))
    {
        mDefaultPreferences.edit().putBoolean("first_launch", false).commit();
        //Put the code here of your first launch
        currentMoney = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //Not the first launch
        currentMoney = current;
    }

}
```

I'll separate them to make anything clearer

```
public void plus(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(R.layout.pluslayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
            TextView money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCool);
            EditText transaction = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);
            int earn = Integer.parseInt(transaction.getText().toString());
            int finalEarn = currentMoney + earn;
            String earnFinal = String.valueOf(finalEarn);
            money.setText(earnFinal);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
}

public void minus(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(R.layout.minuslayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.remove, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
            TextView money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCool);
            EditText transaction = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);
            int loss = Integer.parseInt(transaction.getText().toString());
            int currentMoney = Integer.parseInt(money.getText().toString());
            int finalLoss = currentMoney - loss;
            String lossFinal = String.valueOf(finalLoss);
            money.setText(lossFinal);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
}
```

And finally

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed and restarted.
    TextView money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCool);
    int currentMoney = Integer.parseInt(money.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putInt("current", currentMoney);
}
```

}

I'll leave you just my `MainActivity` Java file as that's probably where the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: Please add what logcat says to your question

Comment: Gonna clear it right away: the logcat said something about the saveInstanceState inserted in the onCreate method, after inserting in on the new method (onRestore) it now doesn't show me anything about errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using your SharedPreferences to store and retrieve the values of the TextViews. You may already be familiar with this process since you retrieve a value from your SharedPreferences object, but just in case, here is a snippet from one of my apps...

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mDefaultPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("last known value", money.getText();
editor.apply();  //this will immediately write your changes in-memory, then start an asynchronous task to write the values to permanent storage on the disc.
```

And to get the value back out...

```
String storedValue = mDefaultPreferences.getString("last known value", 0);
money.setText(storedValue);
```

Comment: Wait, what should I remove? @Chamatake-san

Comment: I mean, keep in mind I need to set the value to 0 at the very first time the app is launched

Comment: How do I use that mDefaultPreferences?? Thanks @Chamatake-san

Comment: I took the mDefaultPreferences from your original code. Basically, anytime you need to save the current value of that `TextView`, you will use the first chunk of code I posted. Examples would be `onSaveInstanceState()` or `onPause()` or `onStop()`. Anytime you need to reload the value into the `TextView`, you will use the second chunk of code I posted. Examples of this would be during `onStart()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`. The key thing to remember is that you have to use the same `String` label when you move the data in and out of the SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes but it it doesn't recognize the symbol mPrefere... When I paste that code on saveInsta..() method, why? @Chamatake-san

Comment: @InssideYou Add this line at the beginning of `onSaveInstanceState()`:
SharedPreferences mDefaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: Yes! On the code you forgot a bracket, a String.valueOf and had to add that last line of code even on the onCreate method, but now it works like a charm! Thanks dude!

Comment: onCreate method: `SharedPreferences mDefaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCool);
        String storedValue = mDefaultPreferences.getString("last known value", String.valueOf(0));
        money.setText(storedValue);`

Comment: onSaveIstance method: `SharedPreferences mDefaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mDefaultPreferences.edit();
        TextView money = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCool);
        editor.putString("last known value", money.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();`

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I'm glad it's working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

In the [Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) it says that builder.create(); should appear after chaining the arguments. I think builder.show() only shows the value immediately and won't store it.

Comment: Then should I write builder.create() instead of .show()?

Comment: yea go ahead and test it, and let me know if it works. :D

Comment: Nope, the Dialog neither pops out :/ @BryanHerrera

Comment: Aww lame. What is logcat saying?

Comment: A moment.. Gonna check

Comment: Mmm it appears that he says.. nothing

Comment: Hmm maybe instead of getting the int from savedInstanceState in your main activity try getting the int from mDefaultPreferences.

Comment: I think I tried, but it says it can't recognize mDefaultPreferences, would you mind showing me where to add it on my code (Yeah I'm a newbie)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89738/discussion-between-bryan-herrera-and-insside-you).